# Setting mailto address to the senders email address

Tags: html, email, mailto

Is there a way to set the the address of a mailto link to the address that sent the email? I have an HTML email that will be sent out by multiple people with an RSVP link that is set with a mailto link and they would like the recipient of the RSVP email to be whoever sent that particular email. Is there a way to do this within an HTML email? My initial thought is no because it's an HTML email but was just wondering if there was a way to make something like this happen.

Comment: Why not send a separate, custom email to each person?

Comment: a mailto link will open the mail application of the user to send a new mail. So the sender will be the configured mail account of the user.

Comment: The number of people sending this particular email will be quite large. And the RSVP mailto link has a pre-populated questionnaire. Basically I'm wondering if there is way to create mailto link that acts as a "Reply" to the sender with the pre-populated email questionnaire.